# tableau density plot histogram without using R

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, density-plot

I am trying to create a density plot similar to this one (created in R):

[image: This one was created in R]

The levels of density (e.g., found in the key) are not needed for this graph, but I am struggling to find a way to create a histogram with a density plot that does not require incorporating R in order to create it. I have been told that a method exists,but can't seem to find it anywhere.

I can find methods to create the histogram with bins, but I cannot seem to find how to include the density plot line. I found an example

[image: example]

from Tableau online, but the user included bouncing back and forth between R and Tableau, which I am trying to avoid doing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm fully understanding the question, though the density is just a mathematical function, so you can create it from scratch- (sadly, I don't think Tableau have built this function in, so you need to create it yourself via a calculated field. Based on the image shown, I suspect this is also what this person has done (e.g. they have a calculated field `[density calc top]`

[Hopefully this youtube video demonstrates it well enough for you to follow?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvE2q0hWIIo)